# python handle json list format to array list

Tags: python, json

use python 3.6

this json： [["10000000000"], ["12000000000"]]

i want get like result like

"data": {"calleeInfo": [{"phone": "10000000000",},{"phone": "12000000000",}]}

Comment: That isn't json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By list generation

```
temp = [["10000000000"], ["12000000000"]]
value = [{"phone": i[0]} for i in temp]
result = {"data": {"calleeInfo": value}}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'data': {'calleeInfo': [{'phone': '10000000000'}, {'phone': '12000000000'}]}}
```